# What functionality does Dropbox provide that Evernote does not?

Tags: macos, file-management, dropbox, evernote

I currently use Evernote as a catch-all storage system, note-taking app, and file transfer system.

What, if anything, would Dropbox add to my capabilities?

(If it matters, I'm an OSX/iphone/ipad user.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Evernote's strong suit is capturing notes, ideas, web snippets and such and then making it easy to synchronize and search that stuff.

Dropbox is all about automatically synchronizing one directory/folder. You save stuff to the Dropbox folder under your home directory -- any files. The Dropbox app synchronizes the files with its server and then with any other devices running Dropbox with your account.

Dropbox cannot grab arbitrary snippets or notes. Evernote does not interact directly with a folder on your disk.

They're complementary applications.

Comment: Thanks for the info (and for correcting my typo- looks like no spell-check in the question heading).   I email or drag files to evernote as it is - sounds like dropbox will work better if I know I'll always want a certain file type, etc. to be available, as I can store those in the right folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Evernote so I don't know if it can do this, but an important feature of DropBox is sharing.  You can selectivly share files and folders with other DropBox users.  This is useful for collaborating on documents with other people, especially on an ad-hoc basis for just a single project.

DropBox also keeps a history of your files, so you can revert to older versions or get back deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

I use Dropbox to sync profiles for programs accross Macs. TextExpander, Google Chrome, and a lot of other apps act the same thanks to Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing files both privately and publicly.  Version backup.  Ample storage for free.  The agent doesn't bog down the system.